# clearing textbox after successful login

Tags: php

I have this problem where I am unable to clear the textbox of the login page. When the user successfully log in and then immediately returns to the login page, he will still see his username and password in the textbox.

I have tried using this code to solve the problem

```
body onload="document.getElementById('name').value='';document.getElementById('pass').value=''"
```

but the problem with this code is it doesn't immediately clear the textbox. I need to refresh the page a couple of times before it works. Is there an alternate way of solving the problem?

Here is my code

```
<?php
    /**** Start Session ****/
    session_start();
    /**** Deletes the data stored in the session ****/
    unset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['REF_ID']);
    unset($_SESSION['REF_FNAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['REF_LNAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['REF_ACCOUNT']);
    unset($_SESSION['COUNT']);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 

<head>

</head>

<body onload="document.getElementById('name').value='';document.getElementById('pass').value=''">

          <form action="admin-exec.php" method="post" >
                <center><?php include('../function/admin_errmsg.php'); ?></center>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="txt_username" placeholder="Username" id="name">
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="txt_password" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
            <br>
            <img id="captcha" class="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
            <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" placeholder="Input Captcha Code Here" />
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">
            <br />[ Different Image ]</a>
            <br>
            <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Let Me In" class="btn" >
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this not the browser performing auto completion of the boxes?  This is a feature of the browser as a convenience to the user - if that's what the user wants to happen, you shouldn't try to override it - it's up to them to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the browser auto filling the fields as there's nothing in the code to populate the values of the inputs.

From a UX perspective though I would expect it to redirect to another page once logged in or if it's a login form in the header I would expect it to no longer be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for your html part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 

<head>
<script>
function clearAll()
{
document.getElementById('name').value='';
document.getElementById('pass').value='';
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="clearAll()">

          <form action="admin-exec.php" method="post" >
                <center><?php include('../function/admin_errmsg.php'); ?></center>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="txt_username" placeholder="Username" id="name">
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="txt_password" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
            <br>
            <img id="captcha" class="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
            <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" placeholder="Input Captcha Code Here" />
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">
            <br />[ Different Image ]</a>
            <br>
            <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Let Me In" class="btn" >
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What makes you think that would be any different to doing it directly in the `onload` attribute without the function call as per the OP's code?

Answer (score 0):

you can add and javascript like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#name").val("");

  )
```